# Using the OpenStreetMap Service in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, openstreetmap

i am trying to learn how to use OSM Service in QGIS using Python.

I wrote this script:

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsDataSourceUri

project = QgsProject.instance()
project.clear()


xml = """
<GDAL_WMS>
    <Service name=”TMS”>
        <ServerUrl>http://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png</ServerUrl>
    </Service>

    <DataWindow>
        <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
        <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
        <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
        <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>
        <TileLevel>19</TileLevel>
        <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
        <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
        <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
    </DataWindow>

    <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
    <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
    <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
    <BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
    <Cache />
</GDAL_WMS>"""

vfn = "/vsimem/osm.xml"
gdal.FileFromMemBuffer(vfn, xml)

rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(vfn, "OSM")
if not rlayer.isValid():
    print("Raster failed to load!")
else:
    project.addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

But when I run It, It print "Raster failed to load!".
Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: Did you share all your code? What happen next the last line? Does your file have the correct content? But I think you should use the TMS provider in QGIS, not GDAL XMl files. I will look for an example.

Comment: yes, i share all my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add OSM layer by using the native TMS provider in QGIS:

```
tms = 'type=xyz&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png&zmax=19&zmin=0'
layer = QgsRasterLayer(tms,'OSM', 'wms')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```